# hex to ascii in bash

Tags: string, bash

I have a binary file containing `ascii` values and `\000`: its name is *input* and this is its hexdump (`xxd -c 1`):

```
0000000: 68  h
0000001: 65  e
0000002: 6c  l
0000003: 6c  l
0000004: 6f  o
0000005: 20
0000006: 00  .
0000007: 20
0000008: 77  w
0000009: 6f  o
000000a: 72  r
000000b: 6c  l
000000c: 64  d
```

I'm trying to create a script to parse this file, and yield the string up to the null byte.

this is my attempt so far:

```
buf=""
for x in $(xxd -p -c 1 input); do
    echo "x   = $x"
    if [ ${x} == 00 ]; then
        echo "break"
        break;
    else
        y=$(echo $x | xxd -r)
        echo "y   = $y"
        echo "buf = $buf"
        buf="$buf$y"
    fi
done
echo $buf
```

The output is:

```
x   = 68
y   =
buf =
x   = 65
y   =
buf =
x   = 6c
y   =
buf =
x   = 6c
y   =
buf =
x   = 6f
y   =
buf =
x   = 20
y   =
buf =
x   = 00
break
```

so at least I'm breaking the loop at the right time, but I don't understand why the assignment is not happening right

Comment: all I had to do was add the `-p` to the `xxd -r`. Worked fine in git bash on windows.

Comment: @PaulHodges Can you show exactly how? I tried changing `y=$(echo "0x$x" | xxd -r)` into `y=$(echo "$x" | xxd -pr)` and it didn't work

Comment: @CIsForCookies `xxd` does not accept merged parameters like that, IIRC. Try `xxd -p -r`,

Comment: ep. I literally just said `y=$(echo $x | xxd -p -r)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

`xxd -r` expects `0x` as a prefix to identify the hexadecimal number. This solved it for me:

```
y=$(echo "0x$x" | xxd -r)
```

Though, I must admit this is weird, because I thought `echo "a" | xxd -p | xxd -r` should result in the original letter

Answer (score 0):

There's a better solution! `head` supports NUL as a line delimiter. Try

```
head -zn1 input
```

In case you need other fields, try

```
head -zn7 input | tail -zn1
```

Comment: I'll check it out tomorrow. Will that still work if the string is in some offset in the file? Something like `cat {input:offset} | head`?

Comment: @CIsForCookies I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you give me an example input and the corresponding expected output?

Comment: Think that before my "hello" there is 5 null bytes and that I'm trying to read the input file from offset 5

Comment: I get `head: invalid option -- 'z'` when using `head -zn1 input` and the wrong output ["hello world"] when using `head -n1 input`

Comment: @cookies what version of head are you running? Run `head --version`. (for me it's GNU coreutils 8.28)